# Max width of an image in mc; defaulting to original width in outlook

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, images, content-builder, outlook

This might be a simple question, but would anyone be able to help me set the max-width of an image in marketing cloud so that the picture doesn't default to its original size when downloaded in outlook? I have many different attributes/styling on this image in mc that I'm at a loss for how and why it is still downloading and displaying at its default (rather large) width and height. I'm assuming it's a simple fix...
(below are images and how it displays in mso and in a browser)

```
    <style>
    [omitting code]
    .width-300{
          width:300px;
          max-width:300px;
          height:auto;
          max-height:200px;
            }
    [omit]
    </style>

    <table class="" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" valign="middle" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
     <tr>
      <td style="padding-bottom:25px" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left">
       <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;" class="container">
        <table class="" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" valign="middle" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
         <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="center" style="padding-right:15px">
            <table class="width-300" width="300" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr><td>
            <a href="%%=concat('https://',@affinityLinkCode,'.mycuhomeadvantage.com/Admin/ListingDetails?ListingId=',@listingId)=%%" target="_blank" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;">
              <img src="%%=v(@image)=%%" alt="House Image" class="width-300" width="300px" valign="middle" style="display:block;" border="0">
                </a></td></tr>
            </table></td>[omit]
```

[image: Image at large in mso]

[image: Image normal size in broswer]

Answer (score 1):

Oh, you're giving me flashbacks to my HTML-email-coding days -- Ouch!

Outlook still has awful support for CSS.  Your best bet is always to use inline CSS instead of writing a style block and using classes.  (Yes, that stinks.)

`Width` and `Max-Width` attributes aren't supported at all.  You'll have to use the HTML `width` property and set it to a fixed value.  I see you're doing that in addition to setting it with CSS in your code.  Try removing the CSS and seeing if that fixes it.

**[EmailOnAcid](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/how-to-code-emails-for-outlook-2016/)** is a great resource for HTML email styling help.

**[CampaignMonitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/email-client/outlook-2007-16/)** has a list of supported CSS attributes for the various email platforms.

Both are worth bookmarking.